# Set PDF Version using iTextSharp

Tags: pdf, itext

Anyone know how to save a PDF as a lower PDF version programmatically using iTextSharp so that you can use certain iTextSharp features that require the PDF to be version 5 or lower?

I'm trying to merge two PDF version 7 documents together and it insists that they be version 5 or lower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How odd.  PDF versions are mostly a suggestion.  PDFs must start with something like:

```
%PDF-1.x
```

Where the X is 0,1,2,...

This is just a clue to the app reading the PDF.  The only clue.  Most "I need version X" requests I see from various customers are bogus.  My fellow iText coders know this, so it strikes me as odd that *iText* is requesting a different version.

*You're sure its **iText** requesting v5?*

At any rate, to answer your question:

Yes, iText can change the version number of a PDF.  Sadly, it can only be done when writing out a PDF, not when reading it in.  You'll have to open the PDF, change its version, and save it again.

You could probably cheat.  Read the PDFs into byte arrays and `pdfBytes[7] = 4;`, then pass those bytes on to a `PdfReader`.

Version 1 of the PDF spec is 1.0
Version 2 is 1.1
...

So if you want pdf version 5, you need to write out "1.4", not "1.5".

If you're not comfortable poking a byte like that, you can parse the whole PDF, change the version, then write it all out again:

```
 PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath);
 PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputStream);
 stamper.setPdfVersion(PdfWriter.PDF_VERSION_1_4);
 stamper.close();
```

You'd then read it in again, and combine it as you have been.

Comment: You were write, I didn't realize I was using PDFSharp and not iTextSharp.  iTextSharp looks much better but I am having an issue [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326506/how-do-i-combine-merge-pdfs-with-fillable-form-fields-using-itextsharp)

Comment: “How odd. PDF versions are mostly a suggestion.” It seems worth being explicit—I came here because I was patching PDFs with embedded fonts. Adobe refused to render the fonts. I set the version number in the stamper to 1.4 and it rendered fine in Adobe. Seems that it takes the version literally at least in that case.

Comment: Also odd.  Adobe tends to work hard to fix "broken" PDFs, including those with bad version numbers.

Comment: I using iTextSharp 5.5.9: stamper.Writer.SetPdfVersion(PdfWriter.PDF_VERSION_1_6); it not working.

Comment: iText has gone through several major version changes since I wrote this answer some 7+ years ago.  OTOH, the docs on SetPdfVersion() now read "If the PDF Header hasn't been written yet, this changes the version as it will appear in the PDF Header.".  I suspect you've already done something to cause your header to be written.  You can fix this by moving your SetPdfVersion so it's the first thing you do with your PdfWriter/PdfStamp once you have it.

Answer (score 5):

```
///for itextSharp 5.4.4
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputStream); 
stamper.Writer.setPdfVersion(PdfWriter.PDF_VERSION_1_4); 
stamper.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
writer.PdfVersion = PdfWriter.VERSION_1_3;

This worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Looks like this is no longer valid, well, at least for me it didn't work. However, I found this and it worked for me: http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/iTextSharp-PDF-version-td3477631.html.

Comment: This link is broken. A prime example of why you should never just link the solution, but also write it explicitly into the answer.