# add a new page to pdf document c#

Tags: c#, pdf, .net-4.0, pdf-generation, itext

I need to add another page in a pdf file created using below code. the next page should also use the same template placed at path:

`HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/InvoiceTemplate/invoiceTemplate.pdf")`

I am using itextsharp library to create documents. Below is the code used to generate pdf.

```
public static void WriteInTemplate(List<Models.Statement> statementList)
{

    string invoiceNumber = statementList.FirstOrDefault().Invoice.ToString().Trim();
    string month = null;
    string day = null;
    string year = null;


    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/InvoiceTemplate/invoiceTemplate.pdf"));
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/reports/" + invoiceNumber + ".pdf"), FileMode.Create);
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, fileStream);


    AcroFields pdfFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;


    pdfFields.SetField("BillToCompany", statementList.FirstOrDefault().BillToCompany.ToString().Trim().ToUpper());
    pdfFields.SetField("BillToContact", statementList.FirstOrDefault().BillToContact.ToString().Trim().ToUpper());
    pdfFields.SetField("CustomerId", statementList.FirstOrDefault().Customer_ID);
    pdfFields.SetField("InvoiceNumber", statementList.FirstOrDefault().Invoice.ToString().Trim());
    pdfFields.SetField("JobNumber", statementList.FirstOrDefault().JobNumber.ToString().Trim());
    pdfFields.SetField("Caller", statementList.FirstOrDefault().Caller.ToString().Trim());


    pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true; // generate a flat PDF 
    pdfStamper.Close();
    pdfReader.Close();
}
```

Comment: see where you have  pdfFields.SetField? use the intellisence to see if it exposes a AddField or add page

Comment: it does not have addPage

Comment: What pdf component are you using..?

Comment: not sure wht you asked.. I am using PDFStamper, PDFReader and acrofields in itextsharp library

Comment: click the link in my answer below

Comment: the link provided by you creates a new doc, i need to add a new templated pdf page.

Comment: See Mark's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326506/how-do-i-combine-merge-pdfs-with-fillable-form-fields-using-itextsharp

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a PDFDocument and then merge the files that you create into it. There is a very good example of this in this link: [Merge PDFs using ITextSharp](http://geekswithblogs.net/bsherwin/archive/2007/06/29/113566.aspx).