# iText7-Community AcroFields being ripped on flatten

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

I created a PDF with Master PDF Editor containing one form text field.
When manipulating that PDF file with `iText7-Community` I manage to find that field and to set its value. However, when I flatten the output PDF file that field is ripped and just disappears.

Bottom line: field shows up fine without flattening and disappears when flattening.

I ran `isXfaPresent()` from `XfaForm` and the response was `false`, so I understand it is indeed `AcroForm`.

So, this is what I tried:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("path-to-file.pdf");
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("path-to-dest-file.pdf");
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);

PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(doc, false);
form.getField("treinamento").setValue(param);
System.out.println("----> " + form.getField("treinamento").value);
form.flattenFields();
doc.close();
```

`System.out` shows the value correctly setup but the output file doesn't show it. If I comment `form.flattenFields()` it does.

Any help on what I should do to fix this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24183403/itext-5-5-fails-to-fill-form

Comment: @BrunoLowagie It's not. I forgot to mention I'm using the itext7-community . Just updated the question. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 0):

Try call `form.getField("treinamento").regenerateField();` after your call to `setValue(...)`

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("path-to-file.pdf");
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("path-to-dest-file.pdf");
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);

PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(doc, false);
form.getField("treinamento").setValue(param);
System.out.println("----> " + form.getField("treinamento").value);
form.getField("treinamento").regenerateField();
form.flattenFields();
doc.close();
```

Comment: Due to timeline, we ended up creating our PDF template with Scribus instead of PDF Master Editor. Sorry for not being able to test your suggestion but thanks for stopping by to help.