# IText merge documents with acrofields

Tags: java, adobe, itext

I currently have a PdfReader and a PdfStamper that I am filling out the acrofields with. I now have to copy another pdf to the end of that form I have been filling out and when I do I lose the acrofield on the new form I copy over. Here is the code.

```
public static void addSectionThirteenPdf(PdfStamper stamper, Rectangle pageSize, int pageIndex){
     PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("/resources/documents/Section13.pdf"));
     AcroFields fields = reader.getAcroFields();

     fields.renameField("SecurityGuidancePage3", "SecurityGuidancePage" + pageIndex);

     stamper.insertPage(pageIndex, pageSize);
     stamper.replacePage(reader, 1, pageIndex);
}
```

The way that I am creating the original document is like this.

```
     OutputStream output = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponseOutputStream();

     PdfReader pdfTemplate = new PdfReader(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("/resources/documents/dd254.pdf"));

     PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfTemplate, output);
     stamper.setFormFlattening(true);

     AcroFields fields = stamper.getAcroFields();
```

Is there a way to merge using the first piece of code and merge both of the acrofields together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what you want exactly, different scenarios are possible, but in any case: you are doing it wrong. You should use either `PdfCopy` or `PdfSmartCopy` to merge documents.

The different scenarios are explained in the following [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6YwDME0Fl1c).

You can find most of the examples in the [iText sandbox](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox).

**Merging different forms (having different fields)**

If you want to merge *different* forms without flattening them, you should use `PdfCopy` as is done in the [MergeForms](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/MergeForms) example:

```
public void createPdf(String filename, PdfReader[] readers) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
    copy.setMergeFields();
    document.open();
    for (PdfReader reader : readers) {
        copy.addDocument(reader);
    }
    document.close();
    for (PdfReader reader : readers) {
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

In this case, `readers` is an array of `PdfReader` instances containing *different* forms (with different field names), hence we use `PdfCopy` and we make sure that we don't forget to use the `setMergeFields()` method, or the fields won't be copied.

**Merging identical forms (having identical fields)**

In this case, we need to rename the fields, because we probably want different values on different pages. In PDF a field can only have a single value. If you merge identical forms, you have multiple visualizations of the same field, but *each visualization will show the same value* (because in reality, there is only one field).

Let's take a look at the [MergeForms2](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/MergeForms2) example:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    copy.setMergeFields();
    document.open();
    List<PdfReader> readers = new ArrayList<PdfReader>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ) {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(renameFields(src, ++i));
        readers.add(reader);
        copy.addDocument(reader);
    }
    document.close();
    for (PdfReader reader : readers) {
        reader.close();
    }
}

public byte[] renameFields(String src, int i) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);
    AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
    Set<String> keys = new HashSet<String>(form.getFields().keySet());
    for (String key : keys) {
        form.renameField(key, String.format("%s_%d", key, i));
    }
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

As you can see, the `renameFields()` method creates a new document in memory. That document is merged with other documents using `PdfSmartCopy`. If you'd use `PdfCopy` here, your document would be bloated (as we'll soon find out).

**Merging flattened forms**

In the [FillFlattenMerge1](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/reporting/FillFlattenMerge1), we fill out the forms using `PdfStamper`. The result is a PDF file that is kept in memory and that is merged using `PdfCopy`. While this example is fine if you'd merge different forms, this is actually an example on **how not to do it** (as explained in the [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6YwDME0Fl1c)).

The [FillFlattenMerge2](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/reporting/FillFlattenMerge2) shows how to merge identical forms that are filled out and flattened correctly:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
    PdfReader reader;
    PdfStamper stamper;
    AcroFields fields;
    StringTokenizer tokenizer;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(DATA));
    String line = br.readLine();
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // create a PDF in memory
        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        reader = new PdfReader(SRC);
        stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);
        fields = stamper.getAcroFields();
        tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, ";");
        fields.setField("name", tokenizer.nextToken());
        fields.setField("abbr", tokenizer.nextToken());
        fields.setField("capital", tokenizer.nextToken());
        fields.setField("city", tokenizer.nextToken());
        fields.setField("population", tokenizer.nextToken());
        fields.setField("surface", tokenizer.nextToken());
        fields.setField("timezone1", tokenizer.nextToken());
        fields.setField("timezone2", tokenizer.nextToken());
        fields.setField("dst", tokenizer.nextToken());
        stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
        stamper.close();
        reader.close();
        // add the PDF to PdfCopy
        reader = new PdfReader(baos.toByteArray());
        copy.addDocument(reader);
        reader.close();
    }
    br.close();
    document.close();
}
```

These are three scenarios. Your question is too unclear for anyone but you to decide which scenario is the best fit for your needs. I suggest that you take the time to learn before you code. Watch the video, try the examples, and if you still have doubts, you'll be able to post a smarter question.

Comment: copy.setMergeFields(); does not exist in my PdfCopy, I already looked up these solutions. I am using 
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

I am looking to see if its because it is outdated now.

Comment: It's outdated. iText 5.0.6 dates from February 4, 2011, that's 4 years ago!

Comment: Hahaha Yeah I noticed once I started looking haha. I am going to see If I can get it working with this new code :). Ill let you know once I test!

Comment: Super helpful! Although I wish there was a way to copy the acrofields over by using stamper.insertPage or something along those lines. Thanks for the help!