# methods copy.setMergeFields(), copy.addDocument(reader) are showing as cannot resolved at compile time

Tags: android, pdf, itext

With reference to the link [For Pdf form merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28566190/itext-merge-documents-with-acrofields)

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
copy.setMergeFields();
document.open();
for (PdfReader reader : readers) {
    copy.addDocument(reader);
}
```

**Here methods copy.setMergeFields(), copy.addDocument(reader) are showing as cannot resolved at compile time. And am using com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy**

Comment: Which version of iText are you using? These methods were introduced in iText 5.5.x (I'm not sure about the x, but if you use 5.5.6, it will work).

Comment: Which version do you use? I just checked, those methods are present in the current itextg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to iText 5.5.6 and you'll notice that the methods are there:

- http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfCopy.html#setMergeFields()
- http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfCopy.html#addDocument(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader)

If you are using an older version of iText (for instance iText 5.3.0), you'll experience the problem you're describing.

Comment: yes.got resolved after updating with latest itextpdf.jar

Comment: OK @karthik, then you should close the question by accepting the answer (otherwise other readers will think the problem hasn't been resolved yet).