# iText Pdf form concatenation is not happening as expected. Furthur behaving unexpectedly

Tags: android, pdf, itext

With reference to [For merging documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28566190/itext-merge-documents-with-acrofields)

- tried implementing this. But first page is showing as expected, next pages will be like half filled and showing without any pdf form backgound i.e of form kind.
- Below is my code snippets..

  ```
  private void addInfo() {
  PdfReader reader = null, readerPage = null, pdfReaderExtraPage = null, pdfReaderExtraPage1 = null, readerD = null;
  //PdfCopyFields copy = null, copyD = null;
  FileOutputStream fosResDoc, fosFinalDoc;
  int indirectLaborDocCount = 1;
  int equipDocCount = 1;

  Document document = null, document2 = null;
  PdfCopy copyTemp = null, copyTemp2 = null;

  try {
      String resultDocPath = Constants.FOLDER_PATH + "ResultDoc.pdf";

      fosResDoc = new FileOutputStream(resultDocPath);
      reader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(Constants.strFilePath));
      //copy = new PdfCopyFields(fosResDoc);
      //copy.addDocument(reader);

      //Before this method i already set values of form for first page. This method is to add extra data/pages if any.
      //Add here am adding that using addDocument.

      document = new Document();
      copyTemp = new PdfSmartCopy(document, fosResDoc);
      copyTemp.setMergeFields();

      document.open();
      copyTemp.addDocument(reader);


      boolean isNeededStudentComments = ((strStudentComments.length() > 0) && (strStudentComments.length() > (StudentCommentsMaxLength * StudentCommentsMaxLines)));
      boolean isNeededTeacherComments = ((strTeacherComments.length() > 0) && (strTeacherComments.length() > (TeacherCommentsMaxLength * TeacherCommentsMaxLines)));

      if (isNeededTeacherComments) {
          int commentsTableCount = 1;
          do {
              String extraPagePath = Constants.FOLDER_PATH + "ExtraPage" + commentsTableCount + ".pdf";
              commentsTableCount++;

              readerPage = new PdfReader(Constants.strFilePath);
              stamper = new PdfStamper(readerPage, new FileOutputStream(extraPagePath), PdfWriter.VERSION_1_5);
              readerPage.setPageContent(1, readerPage.getPageContent(1));
              stamper.close();

              if (isNeededTeacherComments && (strTeacherComments.length() > 0)) {
                  fillTeacherComments();
              }

              changePdfFieldName(extraPagePath, commentsTableCount - 1);
              pdfReaderExtraPage1 = new PdfReader(extraPagePath);
              List<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<>();
              lst.add(1);
              copy.addDocument(pdfReaderExtraPage1, lst);

          } while (populatedTeacherCommentsLength < strTeacherComments.length());
      }

      if (isNeededStudentComments) {
          int commentsTableCount = 1;
          do {
              String extraPagePath = Constants.FOLDER_PATH + "ExtraPage" + commentsTableCount + ".pdf";
              commentsTableCount++;

              readerPage = new PdfReader(Constants.strFilePath);
              stamper = new PdfStamper(readerPage, new FileOutputStream(extraPagePath), PdfWriter.VERSION_1_5);
              readerPage.setPageContent(1, readerPage.getPageContent(1));
              stamper.close();

              if (isNeededStudentComments && (strStudentComments.length() > 0)) {
                  fillTeacherComments();
              }

              changePdfFieldName(extraPagePath, commentsTableCount - 1);
              pdfReaderExtraPage1 = new PdfReader(extraPagePath);
              List<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<>();
              lst.add(1);
              copyTemp.addDocument(pdfReaderExtraPage1);

          } while (populatedStudentCommentsLength < strStudentComments.length());
      }

      copyTemp.close();
      fosResDoc.close();

      readerD = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(resultDocPath));
      fosFinalDoc = new FileOutputStream(Constants.strFilePath);

      document2 = new Document();
      copyTemp2 = new PdfSmartCopy(document2, fosFinalDoc);
      document2.open();

      copyTemp2.addDocument(readerD);

      fosFinalDoc.close();

  } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {

      if(document != null)
          document.close();

      if(document2 != null)
          document2.close();

      if(reader != null) { reader.close();  }
      if(readerPage != null) { readerPage.close(); }
      if(pdfReaderExtraPage != null) { pdfReaderExtraPage.close();  }
      if(pdfReaderExtraPage1 != null) { pdfReaderExtraPage1.close();  }
      if(readerD != null) { readerD.close();  }
      if(copyTemp != null) { copyTemp.close();}
      if(copyTemp2 != null) { copyTemp2.close(); }
      try {
          if(outputStream != null) { outputStream.close(); outputStream = null; }
      } catch (IOException ie) {ie.printStackTrace();}
      if(form != null) form = null;
  }
  ```

  }

  ```
  private void fillTeacherComments() {

  PdfReader pdfReaderExtraPage = null;
  FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = null;
  String tmpNotes = "";

  try {

      pdfReaderExtraPage = new PdfReader(extraPagePath);
      outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReaderExtraPage, outputStream);
      form = stamper.getAcroFields();

      form.setField(fieldKey, "Some information String");

      stamper.close();
      fileOuputStream = new FileOutputStream(extraPagePath);
      fileOuputStream.write(outputStream.toByteArray());
      fileOuputStream.close();
  } catch(Exception e) {
      System.out.println("fillExtraComments(): " +e.toString());
  } finally {
      if(pdfReaderExtraPage != null) { pdfReaderExtraPage.close(); }
      try {
          if(outputStream != null) { outputStream.close(); outputStream = null; }
      } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
      if(form != null) form = null;
  }
  ```

  }
- My requirement is that, i have two comments tables in pdf form and max we have only 8 rows, 4 for one table other for other table.
- And in code level i have two comments arrays of size 10 each. Then in first page am addign 5 values from each array to form tables.
- Next am iterating array one individually and adding to document with name abc.doc. And iterating other array individually and added with name abc.doc
- So, these doc should concatenate and fill 5 rows in two table each of same page.But first page is showing as expected, next pages will be like half filled and showing without any pdf form backgound i.e of form kind.

Comment: What is this for: `readerPage.setPageContent(1, readerPage.getPageContent(1));`? Do you have any idea why you are introducing a `PdfStamper` here? I doubt it if you'll get an answer to your question because your code is not easy to read.

Comment: For instance: in `fillTeacherComments()`, you first create a file in memory after which you immediately write the file to disk. Why do you create the file in memory if you need the file on disk?

Comment: All these strange things make it hard for any third party to help you.

Comment: Can you guide me in formatting the code. And attach any references for adding table row in two pdf pages and concatenate to get singleform with two fields.

Comment: I can only answer questions I understand, and I don't understand wha you mean by *adding table row in two pdf pages and concatenate to get singleform with two fields.*

Comment: * For example pdf can accomodate only 2 students and 5 teachers. I am having 2 students and 5 teachers. So, due to some dependencies i want to fill student s first in one.pdf, then i want to include  one.pdf  content first (using Pdfreader) in other two.pdf , then i want to fill teachers in same two.pdf. Finally , pdf should have 2 students and 5 teachers.