# PDF fill in not merging correctly

Tags: vb.net, itext

We are using an asp.net website with iTextSharp.dll version 5.5.13
We can merge multiple PDF files into one using a stream and it works perfectly. However, when we use a PDF that was created in a "fill-in" function the new PDF file does not correctly merge into the other documents. It merges without the filled in values. However, if I open the filled in PDF that it creates the filled in data displays and prints fine.

I have tried merging the new "filled in" PDF at a later time but it still displays the template file as though the filled in data was missing.

Below code fills in the data

```vb
Dim strFileName As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(strSourceFile)
Dim strOutPath As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Apps/Lifetime/OfficeDocs/Export/")
newFile = strOutPath & strFileName & " " & strRONumber & ".pdf"

If Not File.Exists(newFile) Then
    Dim pdfReader As PdfReader = New PdfReader(strSourceFile)
    Using pdfStamper As PdfStamper = New PdfStamper(pdfReader, New FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create))

        Dim pdfFormFields As AcroFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CUSTOMER NAME", strCustomer)
        pdfFormFields.SetField("YR MK MODEL", strVehicle)
        pdfFormFields.SetField("RO#", strRONumber)

        pdfStamper.FormFlattening = False
        pdfStamper.Dispose()
    End Using

End If
```

Then code below here merges multiple PDF files/paths sent to it

```vb
Public Shared Sub MergePDFs(ByVal files As List(Of String), ByVal filename As String)
    'Gets a list of full path files and merges into one memory stream
    'and outputs it to a browser response.
    Dim MemStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream
    Dim doc As New iTextSharp.text.Document
    Dim reader As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader
    Dim numberOfPages As Integer
    Dim currentPageNumber As Integer
    Dim writer As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, MemStream)
    doc.Open()
    Dim cb As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentByte = writer.DirectContent
    Dim page As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage
    Dim strError As String = ""

    For Each strfile As String In files
        reader = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(strfile)
        numberOfPages = reader.NumberOfPages
        currentPageNumber = 0
        Do While (currentPageNumber < numberOfPages)
            currentPageNumber += 1
            doc.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(currentPageNumber))
            doc.NewPage()
            page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, currentPageNumber)
            cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0)
        Loop
    Next
    doc.Close()
    doc.Dispose()

    If MemStream Is Nothing Then
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("No Data is available for output")
    Else
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + filename)
        HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(MemStream.ToArray)
        HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Flush()
        HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Close()
        HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Dispose()
        MemStream.Close()
        MemStream.Dispose()
    End If
End Sub
```

I expect the "filled in" PDF in the list of files to retain the filled in data but it does not. Even if I try to merge the filled in file later it still comes up missing the filled in data. If I print the filled in file it looks perfect.

Comment: You use a `Document`/`PdfWriter` pair to to import the pages from the `PdfReader`. That way you only copy the page contents. If you want to copy other page properties, too, like annotations (e.g. form widget annotations and free text annotations), you should use a `Document`/`PdfCopy` pair.

Comment: I must be missing something. I don't see any difference in the code.

Comment: `PdfWriter` is different from `PdfCopy`.

Comment: Still fails to work.  I must have missed something in the changed code. I changed the Dim writer line to below. Do I need to change something else?

Dim writer As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy.GetInstance(doc, MemStream)

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58591775/1729265) - `PdfCopy` has to be instantiated differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PdfWriter.GetImportedPage` only returns you a copy of the page contents. This does *not* include any annotations, in particular not the widget annotations of form fields on the page at hand.

To also copy the annotations of the source pages, use the iText `PdfCopy` class instead. This class is designed to copy pages including all annotations. Furthermore, it includes methods to copy all pages of a source document in one step.

You have to tell the `PdfCopy` object to merge fields, otherwise the *document-wide* form structure won't be built.

As an aside, your code creates many `PdfReader` objects but does not close them. That may increase your memory requirements substantially.

Thus:

```
Public Shared Sub MergePDFsImproved(ByVal files As List(Of String), ByVal filename As String)
    Using mem As New MemoryStream()
        Dim readers As New List(Of PdfReader)
        Using doc As New Document
            Dim copy As New PdfCopy(doc, mem)
            copy.SetMergeFields()
            doc.Open()
            For Each strfile As String In files
                Dim reader As New PdfReader(strfile)
                copy.AddDocument(reader)
                readers.Add(reader)
            Next
        End Using
        For Each reader As PdfReader In readers
            reader.Close()
        Next

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + filename)
        HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(mem.ToArray)
        HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Flush()
        HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Close()
        HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Dispose()
    End Using
End Sub
```

*Actually I'm not sure whether it is a good idea to `Close` and `Dispose` the response output stream here, that shouldn't be the responsibility of a PDF merging method.*

*[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28567177/1729265) is a related answer for the Java version of iText; you may want to read it for additional information. Unfortunately many links in that answer meanwhile are dead.*

Comment: Thank you very much!  This really helped me get over a merge issue.

Comment: Also, I wondered if you had any comments regarding the "fill in" code that I am using and listed above.  I found this example a few years ago and it has worked well.

Comment: @user2658418 *"any comments regarding the "fill in" code"* - It looks ok, merely the `pdfStamper.Dispose()` does not make any sense as `pdfStamper` is the `using`variable here anyways.