# is there any possibility to add a PdfPTable to an PdfCopy object?

Tags: java, itext

I am working on a project where itext 2.1.7 is used, I've needed to solve a problem with acrofields which were invisible if `PdfWriter` was used.
But then my `PdfPTable` (which represents navigation page) could not be added anymore
This happened because to add a table to a page `Document.add(PdfPTable)` was used.
The question is: how can i add a `PdfPTable` on a `PdfCopy`, or use `PdfWriter` so that my acrofields will not disappear etc..
Now I have a pdf with acrofields made with `PdfCopy`.
Also how can I reorder pages on the same way with `PdfCopy` ?

//edit
added my stupid workaround to manually edit final output and add there acrofields if they exist, but the links on my index page

I want to be able to add page to a pdf file made of multiple pdf's while keeping acrofields on pages (if they exist) [IText merge documents with acrofields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28566190/itext-merge-documents-with-acrofields)

code which was used to add a table on an `PdfWriter` pdf:

```
      final PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
      table.setWidthPercentage(100);
      table.setWidths(new int[]{5, 1});
      table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
      table.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
      for (List<TrayIndex> indexPage : indexPages) {
      document.newPage();

      //add index title
      final int indexPageNumber = indexPages.indexOf(indexPage) + 1;
      final String indexTitle = "INDEX" + (maxIndexPages > 1 ? indexPageNumber : "");//only add page number, if index consists of multiple pages
      final PdfPCell cellTitle = PdfUtils.createCell(indexTitle,
          largerFont, Rectangle.NO_BORDER, Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
      table.addCell(cellTitle);
      final PdfPCell cellTitleDummyFill = PdfUtils.createCell(" ",
          largerFont, Rectangle.NO_BORDER, Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
      table.addCell(cellTitleDummyFill);

      //add index content
      for (TrayIndex trayIndex : indexPage) {
        final int pageNumber = trayIndex.getPage_nr();
        final PdfPCell cellContent = PdfUtils.createCell(trayIndex.getText(), PdfUtils.createActionGoToPage(writer, pageNumber, PdfDestination.FIT),
            font, Rectangle.BOTTOM, Color.LIGHT_GRAY, Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        table.addCell(cellContent);
        final PdfPCell cellPageNumber = PdfUtils.createCell(Integer.toString(pageNumber),
            font, Rectangle.BOTTOM, Color.LIGHT_GRAY, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        table.addCell(cellPageNumber);
      }
    }

    document.add(table);

    // put the index pages in front of the rest
    document.newPage(); // always go to a new page before reordering pages
    final int numberOfPages = writer.reorderPages(null);
    final List<Integer> pageNumbers = Ints.asList(PdfUtils.getIndicesArray(numberOfPages, 1)); // one-based list of page numbers e.g. [1, 2, ..., n]
    Collections.rotate(pageNumbers, maxIndexPages);
    writer.reorderPages(Ints.toArray(pageNumbers));


  public void addAcrofieldsIfExist(InputStream editedPdfs, OutputStream output, List<TrayIndex> originalPdfs, int fromPage) throws GeneratorException {
Validation.checkIfNull(editedPdfs, "Pdf input stream cant be null");
PdfReader readerEditedPdfs = null;
PdfCopy copy = null;
Document document = null;
try {
  document = new Document();
  readerEditedPdfs = new PdfReader(editedPdfs);
  copy = new PdfCopy(document, output);
  document.open();
  int pages = readerEditedPdfs.getNumberOfPages();
  for (int i = 1; i <= pages;) {
    if (i != fromPage + 1) {
      copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(readerEditedPdfs, i));
      i++;
    } else {
      for (TrayIndex originalPdf : originalPdfs) {
        PdfReader readerOriginalPdf = new PdfReader(originalPdf.getTray().getBytesProcedureData());
        if (i != originalPdf.getPage_nr() + fromPage && (i > pages || readerEditedPdfs.getAcroFields().getFields().isEmpty())) {
          copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(readerEditedPdfs, i));
          i++;
        } else {
          for (int y = 1; y <= readerOriginalPdf.getNumberOfPages(); y++) {
            copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(readerOriginalPdf, y));
            i++;
            readerOriginalPdf.close();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
} catch (Exception ex) {
  throw new GeneratorException(ex);
} finally {
  close(readerEditedPdfs);
  close(document);
  copy.close();
}
```

}

Comment: I still am not sure what you are trying to accomplish. But I somehow get the impression that neither of your attempted options (`PdfWriter`/`PdfCopy`) is optimal. Instead you should consider loading the PDF using a `PdfReader`, arranging the pages using the `selectPages` method, creating a `PdfStamper`, adding a page using `insertPage`, getting its canvas using `getOverContent`, creating a `ColumnText` for that canvas, and adding your table to that new page via that `ColumnText`. But as said above, I'm not sure I really understand which result PDF you want... probably `PdfCopy` + `PdfStamper`?

Comment: `PdfCopy` + `PdfStamper` I've tried already, while I'm using `PdfCopy` I can't add `PdfPTable` with document.add(table); and reorder pages like it is done in the code from my post. (I think this was my first question here where you also was trying to help me)
So I was looking for another solution.
Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Have you considered adding your table by itself to a new PDF (`PdfWriter` based) in memory and then using `PdfCopy` to concatenate this new PDF and your other PDF(s)? Probably it could be done more easily if the actual use case was clearer.

Comment: This might work but I will have the same output which I have now - everything will look like it has to, but actionGoToPage added on ´PdfPCell´ will not work, so I think it requires the whole PDF to add table

Answer (score 0):

Your post is a confusing. Please tell us what you are your steps and what are you trying to get as an end result? E.g.

1. I have an existing PDF file (or files)
2. I want to prepend a new page with a table (some navigation info) to that PDF
3. I want to add form fields / keep the existing fields ...

What I understand is that you use the PdfWriter to prepend a new page with a table with some navigation info on it. But why do you use PdfCopy? PdfCopy is to copy content from one PDF into another PDF. Your fields are probably not visible because if you want to copy form fields from another PDF you have to use PdfCopyFields. And did you consider to use PdfSmartCopy?

So in the end you need to rework your question and your code. You did not post the relevant code part. I don't see how and where you use PdfWriter/PdfCopy etc. Most of the creation of your 1st page with table is irrelevant and doesn't help.

Disclaimer: I would have posted this as a comment but it was too long...

**Update:**
From what I understand now is that you want to do multiple things:

1. Prepend a navigation page
2. reorder pager
3. add form fields (?)

I just checked PdfCopyFields and it extends the PdfWriter. So did you try to use PdfCopyFields and do everything? I think in that case the form fields should remain intact...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've edited my post, I don't think that this code will help you a lot, it wasn't written by me, but the only problem is that all manipulations (merge multiple pdfs, add page numbers and table with links) are made with PdfWriter (I've tried simply merge pdfs with acrofields with PdfWriter and they were not there), the only solution I found is in post, but this is not good enough, it has to be made in other way.