# itextsharp 5.4.4 CopyAcroForm no longer there

Tags: itext

In version 5.4.2 of itextsharp I was able to use: (fragment in VB)

```
Dim pdfWriter As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy 
pdfwriter = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy(outputPDFDocument, New FileStream(destfname, FileMode.Create))
pdfWriter.CopyAcroForm(reader)
```

to copy a form from one document to another.

In 5.4.4 `CopyAcroForm` is no longer there under `PdfCopy` or anywhere else - what is the alternative?

Comment: According to this thread (http://itextsharp.10939.n7.nabble.com/RE-iText-questions-PdfCopy-copyAcroForm-wrong-method-getReaderFile-tt18.html), `CopyAcroForm` was considered obsolete back in 2005 already. I think the reason that it was obsolete was that it didn't do what everyone expected it to do every time. Instead, read Mark's post here that explains a couple of alternatives. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6333751/231316

Answer (score 15):

Please read the release notes for [iText 5.4.4](http://itextpdf.com/release/itext544). It is now possible to use `PdfCopy` to merge PDFs containing AcroForm forms by using the `addDocument()` method. This method is much better than the `copyAcroForm()` method as it also preserves the structured tree root. This is important if your forms are made accessible (cf Section 508 or the PDF/UA standard).

Comment: +1; reading the release notes can be quite an advantage during third-party library updates...

Answer (score 2):

AddDocument() method is cool. Here is my code that read and merge multiple PDFs from SQL server in asp.net . document.Close() is required to flush the content to memory stream.

```
enter code here
    Document document = new Document();
    MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
    PdfCopy writer = new PdfCopy(document, output); // Initialize pdf writer    
    writer.SetMergeFields(); 
    document.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
         PdfReader reader = new PdfReader((Byte[])dr["ImageFile"]);
         writer.AddDocument(reader);
    }
    dr.Close();
    document.Close();
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you also need to call .SetMergeFields() or it won't work:

```
reader = new PdfReader(path);
using (var document = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1))) {
    using (var outputStream = new FileStream(...)) {
        using (var writer = new PdfCopy(document, outputStream)) {
            writer.SetMergeFields();
            document.Open();

            //all pages:
            writer.AddDocument(reader);
            //Particular Pages:
            //writer.AddDocument(reader, new List<int> { pageNumber });
        }
    }
}
```