# Supported PDF versions by iTextSharp

Tags: itext

I was searching around a lot (primary on the ITEXT homepage) and could not find the PDF versions iTextSharp is supporting. Does someone knows which PDF versions are supported by iTextSharp-5.4.1 / 5.4.5 (the latest version).

Comment: Could this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273676/set-pdf-version-using-itextsharp

Answer (score 0):

iText and iTextSharp now are based on the current ISO standard for PDF files ([ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)) and also has implemented explicit support for certain extensions, e.g. signatures, document time stamps, and validation related information from ETSI TS 102 778 parts 1 through 4, which also will be part of the upcoming new ISO standard for PDF files (ISO 32000-2).

In most aspects the PDF references representing earlier versions are subsets of the current specification. Thus, iText (and most other current PDF libraries) can be said to support all those earlier versions, too.

When generating PDFs with iText, you can set the version number to show in the document; you may have to restrict yourself, though, concerning the iText features you use.